# Error trying to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a basic Rails application to run on my Mac OS X 10.6.5. I created a new app called demo (rails new demo), then went into the demo directory and tried to start the app with rails server.
Here is the error message I received:
"/Users/dpetrovi/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]

Abort trap"

I checked bundle install in the demo folder:

```
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.6) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.23) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.13) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.6) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.7) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Ruby, RubyGems, and sqlite3 were installed using MacPorts. Then I used gem to try to install the sqlite3-ruby interface. (sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby). Here is where I first noticed something could be off:

```
Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2...

No definition for libversion

Enclosing class/module 'mSqlite3' for class Statement not known
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2...

No definition for libversion

Enclosing class/module 'mSqlite3' for class Statement not known
```

I had rails running well on my system a few months ago, so I figured maybe I had some duplicates and it was trying to use the wrong one. I ran: `for cmd in ruby irb gem rake; do which $cmd; done` and got:

```
/opt/local/bin/ruby
/opt/local/bin/irb
/opt/local/bin/gem
/opt/local/bin/rake
```

Checking where sqlite3 also gets me: "/opt/local/bin/sqlite3" so they all seem to be in the right place. Obviously /opt/local/bin is in my system path.

If I check gems server, it shows that I have installed sqlite3-ruby 1.3.2 gem. Not sure what the problem could be?

I am using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]. Macports claims this is the latest (although ive seen 1.9.1)

One more thing-- in irb, I tried to check which version of sqlite3 my sqlite3-ruby is bound to, but I can only get this far:

```
:irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'sqlite3'
/Users/dpetrovi/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]

Abort trap
```

Any suggestions? Im hoping I overlooked something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Please follow the question formatting guidelines when writing posts. Indent codeblocks with four spaces and for in-line code examples use \`backticks\`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded to Snow Leopard recently? If so, you need to reinstall MacPorts and all the ports installed with it.

I recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) instead MacPorts installed ruby.

Comment: It was a fresh install of MacPorts. It seems, however, that when I tried to upgrade to the latest Ruby Macports was not getting the correct version. I downloaded RVM and used it to install Ruby (1.9.2) and RubyGems again, and then used the new rubygems to install rails and sqlite3-ruby bindings once more. The server still didn't run on the old app (as expected, I guess) but when I created a new app everything now works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use RVM as mentioned above and then try this in your app's directory:

rm -rf .bundle && bundle install

Comment: Thanks. I used RVM-- there was a conflict between the version of Ruby (1.8.7) and either Rails or sqlite3. In any case upgrading to Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM solved the problem (although the latest 1.9.3 dev version didnt work)

Comment: What do you do when it says `$ rm -rf .bundle && bundle install`
`Bundler::GemfileNotFound` after running that command?

Comment: That means that Gemfile is missing in your project.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. here is how i resolved it.

removed the gem sqlite3-ruby
did bundle install
reinstalled the gem
recreated the rails app

now webrick works fine.